# give player woodland mansion explorer map bukkit

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

Does anyone knows how to give a player a woodland mansion explorer map?

Here is the code:

```
player.getInventory().addItem(new ItemBuilder(Material.HERE).setAmount(1).build());
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`MapCursor`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/map/MapCursor.html). You can get some informations [here](https://github.com/SpigotMC/Spigot-API/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bukkit/map/MapCursor.java) too.

The objective is to create a new map cursor, use [MapCursorCollection](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/map/MapCursorCollection.html).

Then, I think that you should use the [`MapMeta`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/inventory/meta/MapMeta.html) to add it to the item.